# How extract XML data using PHP

Tags: php, xml

I am required to extract the information at a particular "area" of this large collection of xml. But i'm not familiar with extracting xml. I've looked through the site and tried various ways but all i get back is "Error in my_thread_global_end(): 1 threads didn't exit"

Here's the url of the xml i'm getting my data from:
ftp://ftp2.bom.gov.au/anon/gen/fwo/IDV10753.xml

I would to retrieve all the 7 forecast-period located only for the Swans Hill "area".

Help please

Answer (score 3):

I agree that using php's simple xml parser is the way to go with this one.
You can make your life easy here using the `xpath` method of extracting data from the xml.

There's an xpath tutorial here: http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/

And php documentation for it here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php

Try this out

```
<?php

/*
Get the file with CURL
$curl_handle=curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl_handle,CURLOPT_URL,'ftp://ftp2.bom.gov.au/anon/gen/fwo/IDV10753.xml');
curl_setopt($curl_handle,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
$xml_data = curl_exec($curl_handle);
curl_close($curl_handle);
*/

/*
Open the file locally
*/

$xml_data = file_get_contents("weather.xml");
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml_data);
$result = $xml->xpath("//area[@description='Swan Hill']/forecast-period");

date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
foreach ($result as $day) {
    //print_r($day);

    $day_of_the_week = date("l", strtotime($day["start-time-local"])); //start-time-local is an attribute of a result, so use the [] syntax
    $forecast = $day->text; //text is a child node, so use the -> syntax

    printf("%s: %s\n", $day_of_the_week, $forecast);
}
?>
```

**EDIT** More illustrative example

Comment: I can't figure out how to select the element with the type of 'air_temperature_maximum'

I tried using this but it didnt work

$max = $day->xpath("element[@type='air_temperature_maximum']");

this one works:
$min = $day->element[1]; 

but it doesn't give me the proper control over what to display incase one of the field is missing.