# XML Data using attribute as selector

Tags: php, xml

#### How can I return the '3' in:

```
<element type="forecast_icon_code">3</element>
```

#### from this external xml:

ftp://ftp2.bom.gov.au/anon/gen/fwo/IDV10450.xml

#### Here is my function:

```
function state($Sitelink) {

$url = $Sitelink;

$file = $url;
if(!$xml = simplexml_load_file($file))
exit('Failed to open '.$file);

$result = $xml->forecast->forcast-period->element;
print_r($result);
}
```

#### Calling the function using:

```
state("ftp://ftp2.bom.gov.au/anon/gen/fwo/IDV10450.xml")
```

Answer (score 1):

You need some xpath action.

[How extract XML data using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3145990/how-extract-xml-data-using-php?rq=1)

Has an example using the same XML data that should give you a start.

Answer (score 0):

I found that SimpleXMLElement has some trouble parsing elements with hyphens in the middle like you have above in "forcast-period".

I found myself in a similar situation and solved it using xpath.

Refer to the following resource and check usage for SimpleXMLElement::xpath():

[SimpleXMLElement xpath doc](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php)